# Python: difference between 1. and 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I came across some code:

```
dz3 = 1./m * (a3 - Y)
```

Why is `1.` used here instead of simply `1`?

Both seem equivalent:

```
>>> 1 / 4
0.25
>>> 1. / 4
0.25
```

Are there any cases where they are not equivalent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python2

```
>>> 3/2 # returns 1
```

Whereas in Python3

```
>>> 3/2 # returns 1.5
```

As you can see one makes integer division and other makes float division.

If I were to write

```
>>> 3./2 # returns 1.5
```

It performs float division no matter of the Python version I choose. Because float / integer can only result in float.

Also to make integer division in Python 3, you just write

```
>>> 3//2
```

[See for further info](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)

Answer (score 7):

That kind of thing would be used for Python 2 compatibility, where division with two `int` operands was integer division by default. `1.` is a `float` instead of an `int`, so will result in float division regardless of the Python version and whether `m` is an `int`.

Comment: @jezrael Probably as a way of saying "this is trivial, let's not start bombarding this with competing answers".

Answer (score 1):

Ok so previous answers are not totally complete. The main difference between the 1 and 1. is in their type and type of the result of any equation that include float number in python will be float.

That include addition subtraction multiplication exponents and even the integer division as if one operand is float answer will be of type float.

Also as others mentioned it is there mainly for the compatibility with python2 but be aware that in that expression if the one num is float then result will always be float.

```
..# 1. / 4
   0.25
..# 1 / 4
   0.25
..# type(1.)
   <class 'float'>
..# type(1)
   <class 'int'>
..# 1 // 4
   0
..# 1. // 4
   0.0
..# type(1. // 4)
   <class 'float'>
..# type(1 // 4)
   <class 'int'>
```

I changed the interpreter `>>>` to ..# as stack editor shows that in multi line as quote level.

So basically if you want to **ensure** that code snippet will always have a float value you make one of numbers float.